# Translog cost function

Tags: econometrics

Can anyone help to estimate total cost under Translog cost function. I have input output and input cost data. It would be highly appreciated if someone can provide a software demo to estimate the same is given.

Answer (score 1):

This article might be of help: https://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/122709/2/sjart_st0160.pdf

Comment: thanks for your help. But any software that can facilitate the computation??

Answer (score 1):

You can use any software for this purpose. With R for instance you will find examples here:
https://rdrr.io/rforge/micEcon/man/translogCostEst.html
It is probably a good exercise however, to do it by hand...

Answer (score 0):

You can add those constraints to SUR regressions in STATA to replicate Christensen and Greene (1976)